# Group by, then select only records where every value of a boolean column is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have both a MS SQL Database and a postgres database.  A solution in either will work as I can translate it.

We have a `customer_phone` table where the relevant columns are:

```
id, customer_id, phone, is_bad
```

What I need to do is select all the `customer_id`'s from this table that ONLY have `is_bad = true`. So if you have 1 good phone number and 1 bad, you shouldn't appear.

For some reason I'm struggling to find an easy way to do this, I feel like it should be deceptively simple.

This was a start that gives me at least all the customers a count of their good and bad numbers, but I'm wondering if there is a way that doesn't involve having to use subqueries and `in`'s?

```
select  customer_id, is_bad, count(customer_id)
from customer_phone cp
group by customer_id, is_bad
order by customer_id desc
```

Comment: Bit confusing: you've tagged the question postgresql, but in the title you've mentioned TSQL which [is Microsoft's proprietary version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) of SQL. Which database are you using?

Comment: In fact, the title seems to refer to a completely different question! This question has nothing to do with `1:N` or specific types!!

Comment: There is no T-SQL in Postgres

Comment: Make up your mind.  It's for SQL Server or Postgres?????

Comment: It's both, multiple databases.  An answer for either one would suffice as I can most likely translate it to the other.

Comment: @LondonRob Thank you for the edit!  That helped to make it more clear.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most intuitive way I've found to add over a boolean column like this is to `SUM` a column which is `1` when `TRUE` and `0` when `FALSE`:

```
CASE WHEN some_bool THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT id
FROM phones
GROUP BY id
HAVING
SUM(CASE WHEN NOT is_bad THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Check out [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f906/15) which shows the query in action.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the "aggregate function", [`bool_and`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE).

This takes a set of inputs and returns:

> true if all input values are true, otherwise false

In your case, where we want every `is_bad` to be true for a particular customer:

```
select customer_id
from customer_phone
group by customer_id
having bool_and(is_bad)
```

Comment: This is very cool!  I did not realize that postgres had this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select  customer_id
       ,is_bad
       ,count(customer_id)
from customer_phone cp
where not exists(select 1 from customer_phone 
                 where is_bad = true)
group by customer_id, is_bad
order by customer_id desc
;
```

Comment: This is the right approach but I think you have the is_bad filter value reversed.  That should be 'is_bad = false'.  They want only customers that don't have a good phone.

Comment: @Tofystedeth yeah, that's why I used `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Yes, but since you're saying NOT EXISTS `where is_bad = true`, you're getting entries that **don't** have a bad row.  You want ones that don't have a **good** row.  Also, shouldn't there be a `and customer_id = cp.cusomter_id` in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MIN to identify if there are only is_bad values. You just have to cast to Int first.

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer_phone cp
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(cast(is_bad as int)) = 1;
```

Comment: Not sure how I feel about relying on the results of casting from boolean to int. I wouldn't be all that surprised if that behaviour is allowed to change...

Comment: I hope not. I've been casting boolean to int for years

Comment: Ha ha. I hope not too!